# cocos2d sprite order and touch point

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I added 10 sprites on screen all with zValue = 0.

Now under ccTouchesMoved method, I store all touch points and then draw them under -(void)draw method.

My problem is the no matter even if zValue of sprite is 0, if I draw a line with my touches over any sprite it is actually drawn under the sprite (NOT OVER IT).

I tried changing the start and end points to nodeSpace but didn't help.

```
        start = CGPointFromString([touchPoints objectAtIndex:i]);
    end = CGPointFromString([touchPoints objectAtIndex:i+1]);
    start = [self convertToNodeSpace:start];
    end = [self convertToNodeSpace:end];
    ccDrawLine(start, end);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing at z-index 0. If you set the zIndex of your sprites to a negative value they will be drawn behind the line.

Comment: I tried zindex of sprites as negative but that didn't help. I noticed I was adding child to self with z = 1[self addChild:sceneSpriteBatchNode z:1]. After changing it to -1 it worked as expected.